# Return Custom Response on Django Rest Framework Generics Retrieve API View

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I want to ask about how to return custom response on Class Based Views for django rest framework generics retrieveapiview.

I have tried to make class based views and function for return custom response but error "Object of Type is not JSON serializable"

I just want to return custom response like {"msg": "success", "data": queryset data}

```
# My Views
class GetClientDetails(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = TablePVUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GetClientDetails
    lookup_field = 'pv_owner'

    def get(self, request, pv_owner):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(pv_owner=pv_owner, user__is_active=True)
        return Response({'Message': 'Users active loaded successfully', 'data': queryset}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: ahh you forgot to serialize data and you are passing data without serialize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use serializer class attribute as `self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)`, and serialize your data so:

```py
class GetClientDetails(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = TablePVUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TablePVUserSerializer
    lookup_field = 'pv_owner'

    def get(self, request, pv_owner):
        queryset = self.get_queryset().filter(pv_owner=pv_owner, user__is_active=True)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True)
        data = serializer.data
        return Response({'Message': 'Users active loaded successfully', 'data': data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```